# Export to Excel: programmatically create new Excel sheet

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I need to export some data to Excel, and I'm building the document 'manually': strings with \t for new cell and \r\n for new line.

My question is how to insert in similar way new sheet in same document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You export a CSV file, not an Excel file. MS Excel just opens CSV file and integrate file data in a sheet. You cannot have more than one sheet.

For exporting real Excel files you will an Excel library that can be integrated with your programming language.